# Difficulty with query-replace-regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, whitespace, query-replace

I'm having trouble getting query-regex-replace to do what I want. I've read the docs several times and still can't figure it out. Here are a few examples of things I can't figure out how to do with query-regex-replace:

1. Replace a bunch of whitespace on one line followed by "*" with just "*" (get rid of the whitespace.

EDIT - I got this to work with `[[:space:]]+\*` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*` <kbd>RET</kbd>

2. Replace two forward slashes followed by non white space with two forward slashes and white space (insert a space before the first non white space character).

EDIT - I also got this to work with `//\([^[:space:]]+\)` <kbd>RET</kbd> `// \1`

3. Get rid of blank lines (optionally of course because this is a query replace).

EDIT - I still cannot get this to work. Among other things, I tried these:

`)[[:space:]]+{` <kbd>RET</kbd> `) {` <kbd>RET</kbd>

and

`)\s-+{` <kbd>RET</kbd> `) {` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show an example line and the regex you tried.

Comment: I'm new to this forum format. Should I edit the original post or put the examples here? Also, I'm sure I tried at least five things for #1 above. Should I just put the most straightforward attempt?

Comment: Yes, edit the original post.  Please show the regex expressions you tried.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, there are a few options that may be more efficient than `query-replace-regexp`.  Check out [`whitespace-cleanup`](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/11/25/emacs-tip-number-3-whitespace-cleanup/) for (1), [`comment-dwim`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html) for (2), and [`delete-blank-lines`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Blank-Lines.html) for (3). Unless you're batch cleaning up files, the options I suggested should be a better fit.

Comment: Love that `C-x C-o` to delete blank lines. Thanks for the link @Tianxiang Xiong

Answer (score 3):

To replace space and/or tab sequence followed by an asterisk to just an asterisk:

```
[ LiteralTabHere]+\*
*
```

That LiteralTabHere should be a literal tab char. Enter it by pressing C-q C-i.

You need the backslash before asterisk. Because the asterisk is a meta char, it means 0 or more items.

To insert a space before the first non-white-space character after 2 slashes:

```
//\([[:graph:]]+\)
// \1
```

To remove blank lines

```
\n\n\n+
\n\n
```

Each `\n` must be a literal return. To insert literal return, press C-q C-j.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `C-q C-j`? For me, `C-q RET` gives a carriage return (like `\r`), not a newline (`\n`).

Comment: @npostavs you are right! Correcting it. Thanks.

Comment: To remove blank lines one may also use `M-x flush-lines` and when it prompts `Flush lines containing match for regexp` Enter `$` and hit `Return` key

Comment: @Prasanna you mean with `^$`. That flush all blank lines, sometimes one wants multiple blank lines collapsed to just one.

Comment: This is all great stuff. Thanks much. I am still having problems with replacement involving newlines. For instance, to replace ")" followed by blank space (including newlines) followed by "{" with ") {", I tried:
")[ \t\n]+{"
") {"
It didn't work.

Comment: @Prasanna. I think you meant use the string "^$" for flush-lines. That works well though because it operates on a region, unlike delete-blank-lines. Still having trouble with other regexp replace operations that operate over line breaks, though.

Comment: Actually, the problem with whitepspace in these emacs commands seem more widespread. If you put "[ \t]" in a Regexp I-Search, it will find the character "t", not TAB. If you put a literal tab (as the helpful prompt tells you to do), it won't work at all! How in heck do you _really_ specify a TAB (and possibly other whitespace chars) in these minibuffer commands?

Comment: @AndrewVoelkel literal tab should work, as well as literal return inside a square bracket. To match the curly bracket, it needs a backslash in front, as it is also a meta char. I typically check the elisp manual for regex needs, http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html#Syntax-of-Regexps if you haven't seen that page.

Comment: might also checkout `delete-trailing-whitespace`, `whitespace-cleanup`, or this command to remove blank lines http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_compact_empty_lines.html

Comment: @XahLee: I tried literal tab (as I thought I indicated), I've also played around with literal return. I just don't get the results that folks here claim that I will get. The point about backslashing the return is well taken, but trying to put the open curly brace in the replacement text (with or without the backslash) causes an error. It's different in lisp code, but in that case the space in the replacement text disappears. The results seem to be far more random than the solutions here (which seem reasonable on their face) indicate that they would be

Comment: @AndrewVoelkel might do a separate post. Be sure to be explicit, give the search text example, the regex you used (or what keys you pressed to enter them such as literal tab), and the command you used. Focus on 1 question would be good.